# Lotus Notes and VBA Checking Email Address in Public Address Books

Tags: vba, lotus-notes

I'm trying to figure out how to check whether an e-mail address is in the public address book by using VBA.  I found some code on the Web, modified it but the code gives an error 91 at line, "Set doc = view.GetAllDocumentsByKey(ChkEmailAddr)."  I think that the problem has to do with the declaration type of the variable "view" or the type of view in the line "Set view = b.GetView("People\By Internet Mail")."

I'm pretty certain that I have all of the proper references activated.  "Lotus Notes Domino Objects" and "Lotus Notes Automation Classes" are chosen.

I tried to get a list of views but I couldn't figure out how to do it.  Do you see the error in my code or have ideas as to what I could try to do some troubleshooting?

```
  Sub CheckEmailAddress()

 Dim books As Variant
 Dim view As lotus.NotesView
 'Dim view As Object
 Dim doc As NotesDocumentCollection
 Dim dc As NotesDocument
 Dim done As Variant
 Dim docarr(3, 50) As Variant
 Dim ChkEmailAddr As String

 ChkEmailAddr = "user@example.com"     

 Set Session = CreateObject("Notes.Notessession")

 books = Session.AddressBooks
 done = False

 For Each b In books
   ' check every public address book,
   ' unless we're already done
   If (b.IsPublicAddressBook) Then
   Debug.Print TypeName(b)

     Call b.Open("", "")
     Debug.Print b.Title
     ' look up person's last name
     ' in People view of address book


     Set view = b.GetView("People\By Internet Mail")
     Debug.Print TypeName(view)
     'Debug.Print view
     'Set view = b.GetView("main")
     'Debug.Print TypeName(view)
     Set doc = view.GetAllDocumentsByKey(ChkEmailAddr)
     ' if person is found, display the phone number item
     'from the Person document
     If Not (doc Is Nothing) Then

        For j = 0 To doc.Count
            docarr(0, j) = doc.GetNthDocument(j).Items(11).Text
             docarr(1, j) = doc.GetNthDocument(j).Items(93).Text
            docarr(2, j) = doc.GetNthDocument(j).Items(95).Text
            docarr(3, j) = doc.GetNthDocument(j).Items(14).Text
        Next j
     End If
   End If
Next b
 findEmailLotus = docarr
```

End Sub

Comment: I obtained the code from here: http://www.teachexcel.com/excel-help/excel-how-to.php?i=307100

Answer (score 8):

I'm sorry to say this, but you have a *lot* of issues here. Whoever wrote that code that you started from did not know what he or she was doing.

First of all, unless you are requiring that the Notes client is running while your code is running, you should be using `Lotus.NotesSession` instead of `Notes.NotesSession`.  (The former corresponds to the "Lotus Notes Domino Objects", and uses COM to talk to the Notes APIs, and the latter corresponds to the "Lotus Notes Automation Classes, and uses OLE to talk to the Notes client to talk to the APIs - hence the requirement that the client must be running.)

Secondly, you haven't mentioned what version of Lotus Notes you are dealing with, but more recent versions (8 and above) include the `NotesDirectory` class, which includes a [LoookupNames](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_LOOKUPNAMES_METHOD_DIRECTORY.html) method that would probably be a better solution for you than writing your own code to loop through address books.

Third, after doing your `set view` operation, you really ought to be doing an `If Not view is Nothing` test. That will tell you whether or not you actually have a problem opening the view.

Fourth, `doc` is a really bad variable name for the return value from `GetAllDocumentsByKey`. In 20+ years of writing Notes code, I can say that anybody reading Notes code expects the variable name `doc` to always refer to a single document. You are getting a `NotesDocumentCollection`, not a single document.  Do yourself a favor and change it to `docs` or `dc`, or just about anything except `doc`.

Fifth, using `GetNthDocument` in this context is usually not recommended.  It performs very badly in large collections. Even worse, however, is that you are calling it four times when you could be making only one call per iteration. Instead of a `For` loop, consider changing it to a call to `GetFirstDocument` followed by `While Not doc is Nothing` loop that retrieves your item values and stores them in your array, and then calls `getNextDocument` at the bottom of the loop.

Sixth, that code referencing `.Items(11)`, `.Items(93)`... that's just plain wrong. The available items within any given document are variable because Notes is schemaless. Those item numbers will refer to different fields for different people - i.e., essentially random values.  That can't possibly be what you want. You should be using `getFirstItem()` calls with the actual names of the items that you really want to be putting in your array. You will need to study the field names used in the Domino Directory to figure this out. I recommend [NotesPeek](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24005686) as a good tool for exploring Notes databases and/or just opening up the Domino Directory in the Domino Designer client and looking at the Person form (and associated subforms) to figure out what you need.

As to the actual error you asked about, my guess is that by adding the recommended test of `If Not view Is Nothing` you will gain more information, but perhaps not enough. You haven't mentioned what your debug prints are generating, but I believe there are some cases where the title is available even if the database was not successfully opened, so I don't think you should trust that as a test of whether the call worked. In fact, you really shouldn't just be doing a `Call db.open("","")` call. You should be doing an `If db.open("","") = true` to test whether it actually worked.

Comment: Come to think of it, though, the NotesDirectory class and LookupNames method may not be exposed through the COM interface, so it may not be an option from VBA no matter what the Notes version is. I'm not sure about that.

Comment: Your fifth point (efficiency of GetNthDocument) is the least of his worries. :-) I'm reminded of Tom Christiansen's advice: "Correctness, maintainability, and efficiency, and IN THAT ORDER. Because if you don't care if the code is correct, I can make it MUCH more efficient!"

Comment: @RichardSchwartz Hi Richard, I am very sorry to post this here but I was trying to contact you as you are a pro of Lotus and have strong knowledge on it. I have a problem with creating Lotus.NotesSession . I posted a question explaining my issue but basically Lotus Domino Objects does not work on VBA 64-bits. Is there a way to make it work? Thank you

Comment: As per this IBM technote (http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21454291), the Lotus Notes/Domino object classes are not supported in a 64-bit environment. That said, 32-bit applications can call them in a 64-bit environment and the (mostly) work, but you may have to manually register nlsxbe.dll since the installer (in some versions, anyhow) did not do that. As far as I know, however, 64-bit VBA probably cannot call these classes. You may be able to use Domino Access Services instead.

Comment: Here's a link to Domino Access Services. Note that you will need to have it enabled on the server, and it is not as fully-featured as the classes, but it does provide many feature. https://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/xpAPIViewer.xsp?lookupName=IBM+Domino+Access+Services+9.0.1#action=openDocument&content=catcontent&ct=api

Answer (score 2):

For people who know lotus notes, it's trival.  For those that don't, there might be an easier way using web access.

Request this address
Keep your cookies

```
http://server/names.nsf?login&username=MYUSERNAM&password=MYPASSWORD
```

Then access this url and look for a 404 status or a 200 status

```
http://server/names.nsf/($Users)/email@domain.com?opendocument
```

Of course, that requires that you have web access enabled on your server and in many cases putting your password in your code is bad, and it won't work if your servers are configured in some ways.

Before coding, test it on your server.